# $f:\ell_1 \to \ell_1$ by $f((x_n)) = (x_ny_n)$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$f:\ell_1 \to \ell_1$ by $f((x_n)) = (x_nz_n)$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous where $(z_n)\in \ell_\infty$

Let $x=(x_n)$ and $y=(y_n)$ both in $\ell_1$

$$||f(x) - f(y) ||_1 = ||(x_nz_n)_n - (y_nz_n)_n||_1 = ||([x_n-y_n]\cdot z_n)_n||_1= ||(x_n-y_n)_n||_1\cdot ||(z_n)_n||_1 \ \text{(CAN WE DO THIS??)} \leq ??$$ How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwartz says that $:|ab|\leq \|a\|_1\|b\|_\infty$, will provide a better justification of what you're trying to attempt.

Comment: I don't think it follows from Cauchy Schwartz

Comment: Yes, it does. Let $a:=x_n-y_n$ and $b:=z_n$. Notice that $|a\cdot b| = \|(ab)_n\|_1$. Sorry, there's a missing $\cdot$ in $|a\cdot b|$ in my last comment.

Comment: @AlexR. This is not Cauchy-Schwartz but Hölder. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\|((x_{n}-y_{n})z_{n})_{n}\|_{1}&=\sum_{n}|(x_{n}-y_{n})||z_{n}|\\
&\leq\sum_{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|\|(z_{n})_{n}\|_{\infty}\\
&=\|(z_{n})_{n}\|_{\infty}\sum_{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|\\
&=\|(z_{n})_{n}\|_{\infty}\|(x_{n}-y_{n})_{n}\|_{1}\\
&=\|(z_{n})_{n}\|_{\infty}\|(x_{n})_{n}-(y_{n})_{n}\|_{1}\\
&=\|(z_{n})_{n}\|_{\infty}\|x-y\|_{1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: @Abhay, there is only one variable is running, no need to have the extra $k$.

Comment: oh so $k $ would be running in case I had chosen sequences in the space instead of single elements $x$ and $y$

Comment: can you explain a bit how the proof would go incase I had taken sequences (of sequences )in this space  instead of elements (sequences)

Comment: That doesn't do the proof for showing uniform continuity.

Comment: It does, it's sequential characterisation of uniform continuity. how would $f(x_n) $ look like where $x_n$ is sequence in $\ell_1$? will it look like $(x_n^k z_k)_n$?

Comment: For $x^{k}=(x_{1}^{k},x_{2}^{k},...)=(x_{n}^{k})_{n}$, then $\|f(x^{k})\|_{1}=\displaystyle\sum_{n}|x_{n}^{k}||z_{n}|$.

Answer (score 0):

No because $\sum_n|z_n|$ may be infinite.

But since $z_n$ is bounded we have that $\sum_n|(x_n-y_n)z_n| =\sum_n||x_n-y_n||z_n| \leq M\sum_n|x_n-z_n|=M||x-y||$$

where $M=\sup_n|z_n|$